# Stored procedure with date and date-1 parameter

Tags: sql-server

The query below allow me to get data from the year 2019 and 2018 :

```
SELECT
    [DATE] = GL_DATEPIECE
    [STORE] = GL_ETABLISSEMENT,
    [RAYON] = GL_FAMILLENIV1,
    [SALES] = SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(GL_DATEPIECE) = 2019 THEN [GL_TOTALTTC] ELSE 0 END)
    [SALES Y-] = SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(GL_DATEPIECE) = 2018 THEN [GL_TOTALTTC] ELSE 0 END)
FROM GCLIGNEARTDIM
WHERE 
    GL_DATEPIECE BETWEEN '2019-11-01' AND '2019-11-02'
    OR GL_DATEPIECE BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-11-02'
GROUP BY GL_ETABLISSEMENT, GL_FAMILLENIV1, GL_DATEPIECE
```

I want to create a procedure to get data [SALES] for the entered date, and data for the previous year [SALES Y-]

EX : if i type in the procedure parameter : @StartDate : '2019-10-01' & @EndDate : '2019-11-01' then i should get the [SALES] data from this period.

And Data of the previous year for [Sales-1] : '2018-10-01' & '2018-11-01'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your statement *"I want to create a procedure to get data [SALES] for the entered date, and data for the previous year [SALES Y-]"* this says to me that if you provide the date `20191103` you want the sales data for `20191103` and `20180101` to `20181231` inclusive.

The logic seems odd, but seems like you just need this in your `WHERE`:

```
WHERE GL_DATEPIECE = @DateParam
   OR (GL_DATEPIECE >= DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, @DataParam)-1,0)
  AND  GL_DATEPIECE < DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, @DataParam),0));
```

Assuming that `GL_DATEPIECE` is a `date` and not a `datetime`.

---

Based on the new information:

```
WHERE (GL_DATEPIECE >= @StartDate AND GL_DATEPIECE <= @EndDate)
   OR (GL_DATEPIECE >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @StartDate) AND GL_DATEPIECE <= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @EndDate))
```

Again, assumes that `GL_DATEPIECE` is a `date`, not a `datetime`.